# Rounding two decimal places - not finding the right formula

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

I can't seem to find the correct formula for having two decimal places in my code. Right now, it's rounding to three decimal places when I click on the first option in regards to calculations (not that 3 decimal places means anything. But regardless of the result, it should round to 2 decimal places). This is my last attempt:

```
$('#a_is_valid').one('click', function(){
    if ($('#code_promo').val() == 'promocode')
        {$('#gtotal').val($('#gtotal').val()-($('#gtotal').val()-        
            (($('#gtotal').val()*.75)))).fixed(2);

    }
})
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `.fixed()` method built into it, and seems that google is showing that plugins that use that method are for positioning things on a page, not specifying decimal point (math).

Comment: I don't know about that, because without it, I get 39 instead of 39.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a number (or string representing a number), why not just do this:

```
var number;
var output = (Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

In your case, it looks like you'd want:

```
$('#a_is_valid').one('click', function(){
     if ($('#code_promo').val() == 'promocode')
        {$('#gtotal').val((Math.round($('#gtotal').val() * 75) / 100).toFixed(2));
```

Math.round (appropriately enough) rounds to the nearest integer, so you'll have to do a bit of magic.  Multiply by 10^(number of decimal places you want) - in your case, 10^2 or 100, round, and then divide by the same number.

In the example I made specifically for you, you'll notice I multiply by 75: 0.75 * 100.

It might be easiest to see this using a function:

```
function roundToNPlaces(n, val) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, n);
    return (Math.round(val * multiplier) / multiplier).toFixed(n);
}
```

Then you could simply set your gtotal as follows:

```
$('#gtotal').val(roundToNPlaces(2, $('gtotal').val() * 0.75));
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aW44n/).

See:

- [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) **NOTE**: This documentation provides an implementation similar to (but more complex than) the code I gave.  If you copy their entire `Decimal rounding` example in to your code (before the first time you need to use it), you can then just use `Math.round10($('#gtotal').val() * .75, -2);`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/aW44n/1/
- [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: This works nicely. Although, instead of rounding to 38.81 (due to 38.805) it rounds up to 39.00. I thought math.round would round two decimals without rounding the whole thing?

Comment: @KungFuFrontEnder Ah.  I hadn't thought of that.  Hang on, let me make an edit.

Comment: @KungFuFrontEnder Check out my edit, that should be what you need.

Comment: Awesome edit. I will save that one! :D I did that math of mine a while back and it took me forever lol. I swear, using JS in this form for calculations can be back breaking. Kudos for both the edit and the extra explanation Scott. It's well explained :) Thank you for the links. Btw, is math.round10 actually supposed to work on that link? I had tried that before, but it would break the code.

Comment: @KungFuFrontEnder You would need to copy that entire second example from MDN, and put it as a script in your page before you call it, but then yes, you should be able to do `Math.round10(38.805, -2)`.  [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/aW44n/1/)